# Simple questions about slang

Tags: discussion, review

Someone asked the difference between [pwned / owned](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/71921). I saw it in the edit queue. I almost voted to delete, but ended up skipping it because I wasn't sure. Would this be considered "very low quality?"

Answer (score 5):

Slang is on-topic, but "what does a word mean" is usually not, because there are places to go to look up definitions. We have a list of general references and we expect that users try some of those. If they can't understand what they've found, or come up empty-handed, and they explain what research they've done and what their problem is, then their question is on-topic.